# Spring data JPA - No qualifying bean found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am going to have a simple test with `spring data jpa`.

I have a simple `pojo` , an interface , and a `runner` application.

Here is my code:

```
package aa.bb.cc.repository;

@Repository
public interface ContentRepository extends CrudRepository<Content, Long>{
}
```

And, i have a simple `POJO`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content {

public Content(String name, String title, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
private String title;

@NotNull
private String description;
...
}
```

And, `Application` class:

```
package aa.bb.cc.repository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(ContentRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save two contents
            repository.save(new Content("name1", "title1", "description1"));

            // fetch all Contents
            log.info("Contents found with findAll():");

            for (Content eachContent : repository.findAll()) {
                log.info(eachContent.toString());
            }
            log.info("");
        };
    }
}
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.185</version>
</dependency>
```

I get this exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [aa.bb.cc.repository.ContentRepository] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`

I saw some related problems but can't solve this problem.
What is the solution?

**UPDATE**

`spring-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="aa.bb.cc.repository"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ this is exactly the example you are dealing with, can you please make sure that your pom.xml looks exactly the same. Cause other than that everything you have posted seems the same

Comment: code example for spring boot and data jpa : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put `ContentRepository`, `Content` and `Application` in the same package. If tou need different packages, annotate `Application` with:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository.package")
@EntityScan("entities.package")
@ComponentScan("other.components.package")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to specializt answer you can add the @Repository annotation:

```
package aa.bb.cc.repository;

@Repository
public interface ContentRepository extends CrudRepository<Content, Long>{
}
```

Comment: even  your updated question does not contain `@Repository`, which is necessary. Why are you using the code-markup (this is `code markup`) for random words? That looks very weird and makes no sense

Comment: @specializt I added `@Repository`

Answer (score 1):

Well your example works in my env without xml configuration. The two things that I had to fix was:

- Add no-parameter constructor
- Add identifier field with `@Id` annotation (`@Id private Long id = 5l;`)

If you still have a problem with this, I can upload it to my github repository and post link here.

Comment: I still have the same problem, please show your updated git link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances), you need to activate your repository package inside of your spring configuration, like so :

```
<repositories base-package="aa.bb.cc.repository" />
```

Comment: See `UPDATE` , I have been added the spring config file.